# How to use VBA to filter via a Pivot slicer?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a macro which ultimately extracts a PDF.

Of course what is displayed on the PDF depends on what the pivot is filtered by, in this case it is filtered using a slicer.

I need to extract the PDF for the current month it is filtered on +3 months.

How do I do this? So for example, if the user has the slicer selected on March, the macro will extract the PDF for March only but I'll need it to also extract April,May and June in the same PDF file (so 4 pages in the file). I hope this makes some sense.

Is there a way in which you can code the macro to select month+1,month+2 etc?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, if user selects a single month in the slicer you want VBA macro to additionally select month+1, +2, +3 in the slicer?

This VBA macro does it. You can use this as a basis to get you started:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Select4Slices()

Dim slicer As SlicerCache
Dim slice As SlicerItem
Dim selectNextOne As Boolean
Dim selectedCount As Integer

Set slicer = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(1)
For Each slice In slicer.SlicerItems
    If slice.Selected Then
        selectNextOne = True
        selectedCount = selectedCount + 1
    Else
        If selectNextOne Then
            slice.Selected = True
            selectedCount = selectedCount + 1
        End If
    End If

    If selectedCount >= 4 Then
       Exit For
    End If
Next slice

End Sub
```

Comment: I need the macro to put each month into a pdf file as separate pdf sheets

Comment: What does it do currently? Are you getting the PDF file at all?